# What is the standard socket timeout(seconds) in Ruby socket programming?

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, stream, timeout

I am writing a Ruby client which will open tcp socket and stream data.

If I could not able to open socket within 20 secs I will trigger the Timeout error.

```
begin
  Timeout::timeout(20) { socket = open_socket(host, port) }
rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
  puts "Failed to connect to server"
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "Timeout error occurred while connecting to the server"
end
```

My open_socket method is given below.

```
def open_socket(host,port)
  TCPSocket.new(host,port)
end
```

Code works fine. My question is

1. What is the standard timeout in secs in socket programming?
2. Does the timeout in secs can be setup according to our need?

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 articles that seem to confirm the timeout as 20 seconds:

- In [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464551/shortening-socket-timeout-using-timeouttimeoutn-does-not-seem-to-work-for-me)
- In [Linux](http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout) (not ruby-specific)

The second article seems to imply that the timeout period is defined by the OS.

I do not have a answer for your second question.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how you do it.The default value of timeout is 10 seconds.

timeout( sec) { ...}

Executes the block and returns true if the block execution terminates successfully prior to elapsing of the timeout period,
otherwise immediately terminates execution of the block and raises a TimeoutError exception.

```
require 'timeout'
status = timeout(5) {
# something that may take time
}
```

Comment: This is ruby-implementation specific (I am pretty sure that it might not work on Jruby / rubinius). Moreover, using Timeout.timeout is in general a bad idea. Performance: Timeout.timeout works by spawning a thread (costly). Functionality: Timeout.timeout depends on the blocking call being interruptible. Fragile: it works by raising an exception in the block, which can happen at any place. For instance, it could raise just after the socket got constructed, which would lead to a leak (the socket would be closed only when the GC got started)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the send/recv timeout can be accessed using setsockopt/getsocktopt.

Do man 7 socket and look for the SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO options. setsockopt/getsockopt is available on socket objects in Ruby.