# What kind of example url I can use that will immediately cause a request to fail?

Tags: html, http, url, ip

What is the "official" url I should use if I want to indicate just a resource that fails as soon as possible?

I don't want to use www.example.com since its an actual site that accepts and responds requests and I don't want something that takes forever and fails from a timeout (like typing using a random, private IP address can lead to).

I thought about writing an invalid address or just some random text but I figured it wouldn't look as nice and clear as "www.example.com" is.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10456044

Comment: You *could* make a script that just immediately returns whatever error code you want.

Comment: @Rocket: hmm, 192.0.2.0 isnt good for me, since it is taking around 30s to finally timeout, but the idea of starting the address with 0 seems to work.

Comment: @web_bod: I want the moral equivalent of "www.example.com" for things that are meant to fail (while still being immediately recognizeable as an URL or IP address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an invalid IP, trying using `0.0.0.0`.

The first octet of an IP cannot be `0`, so `0.0.0.0` to `0.255.255.255` will be invalid.

For more info, see this question: [what is a good invalid IP address to use for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10456044)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735:

> 192.0.2.0/24 - This block is assigned as "TEST-NET-1" for use in documentation and example code.  It is often used in conjunction with domain names example.com or example.net in vendor and protocol documentation.  As described in [RFC5737], addresses within this block do not legitimately appear on the public Internet and can be used without any coordination with IANA or an Internet registry.  See[RFC1166].

Comment: Why do requests to `192.0.2.0` take ~30 sec to timeout, but `0.0.0.0` times out immediately?

Comment: @Rocket: I have no idea. Could be the browser I am using, could be the proxy server, I really dont know.

Comment: @missingno: My guess is that it has to actually try to connect to `192.0.2.0` whereas `0.0.0.0` is an invalid IP, so it doesn't even try.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.invalid`, as per [RFC 6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761#section-6.4):

> The domain "invalid." and any names falling within ".invalid." are special [...] Users MAY assume that queries for "invalid" names will always return NXDOMAIN responses.

So a request for https://foo.invalid/bar will always fail, assuming well-behaved DNS.

Related question: [What is a guaranteed-unresolvable (but valid) URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39286127/320036)

Answer (score 0):

if it's in a browser then **about:** is fairly useless - but it would be better if your service returned the correct HTTP status code - e.g. 200 = good, 404 = not found, etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: But that won't fail, will it?