# What is a guaranteed-unresolvable (but valid) URL?

Tags: dns, integration-testing

I have many automated integration tests. Some of them are negative-case tests, which make sure that my system correctly reacts to being given data that it can't successfully use - such as being told to find resources on a remote host which does not exist.

However, this means I want the system under test to actually reach out and try to resolve the host, and I want it to always fail. But I don't know a way to guarantee that a given URL will result in a "Unknown Host" DNS response. I could try to make ludicrously-long and weird domain names, but that makes tests harder to read, and ultimately is still brittle in that *someone* could still bind something to that ludicrous domain name.

Is there a well-known "always-unresolvable" (but valid) domain or convention that I can use, without having to worry about the configuration of my (or anyone else's) DNS servers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [RFC2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) (Reserved Top Level DNS Names)

> 2. TLDs for Testing, & Documentation Examples
>
> ".invalid" is intended for use in online construction of domain
> names that are sure to be invalid and which it is obvious at a
> glance are invalid.

This was explained in more detail in [RFC6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761#section-6.4) (Special-Use Domain Names), with lots of `SHOULD`s and `MAY`s and only one `MUST`:

> DNS Registries/Registrars MUST NOT grant requests to register
> "invalid" names in the normal way to any person or entity.

Still, I think you `SHOULD` be fine with using `something.invalid`.