# launcher.rb for selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, webdriver, watir

We are using watir webdriver to test our applications.   Currently I have 20 watir tests kicking off every 1 or 3 minutes on a linux server.   Due to the way firefox works, we would constantly have tests fail to run because of it's locking port 7055 during launch.  Tests that start at the same time would eventually time out if the port wasn't released in time.

After tons of experimenting, I seem to have been able to get around this issue by modifying this file:

gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb

I added this bit of code near the top to assign a random locking port instead of just the default 7055.   This seems to have helped a lot, only seeing the rare failure now.

Asking if there is a better way to do this or if this could introduce any problems?

```
      ### added to attempt to reduce unable to open firefox issues
      if @port == 7055 then
            @port += rand(2000)
            puts "PORT: #{@port}"
      end
```

Anyone else messed with this?   I'm pretty new to ruby so guessing there is a far better way to script that.

Thanks for any input you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the firefox launcher.rb I think you are better off incorporating some logic at each of your scripts. Something like this might help!

Have a look at the link below:
[Ruby - check if a port is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517219/ruby-see-if-a-port-is-open)