# Checking if Port is Open in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3.2 app, I'm using embedded javascript charts from [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/).  However, it seems that [port 443 must be opened for it to show](https://getsatisfaction.com/tradingview/topics/doesnt_work_choose_a_stock_to_chart_and_nothing_happens?from_gsfn=true).  Therefore, I'm trying to do a check on if the port is open for the user, and if not, show something aside from the chart.

I found this post, ["Ruby - See if a port is open"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517219/ruby-see-if-a-port-is-open) and have been working of this answer:

```
require 'socket'
require 'timeout'

def port_open?(ip, port, seconds=1)
  Timeout::timeout(seconds) do
    begin
      TCPSocket.new(ip, port).close
      true
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
      false
    end
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  false
end
```

However, I modified it to be:

```
def port_open?(ip, port=443, seconds=1)
```

since the port to check will always be the same for me.

I'm calling the method like this:

```
@ip = request.remote_ip
test = port_open?(@ip)
```

I discovered the issue when I was behind a firewall.

What I don't understand is that I can see the chart now that I'm not behind a firewall, yet if I run the code below locally, I can see the chart, but I receive `false`.

However, if I change the `port=3000` I receive true.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ports under 1000 are protected by the system and need to be run with root privileges. At first glance, I'd guess this is what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Port 443 is the normal channel for SSL (https) connections -- it would be quite surprising if a company set outbound restrictions on this port on their firewall.  More likely, it's the IP address of the site that may be restricted.

Get to a command line and try with telnet.  First try something you know works, like google

```
> telnet google.com 443
> Trying 74.125.226.231...
> Connected to google.com.
> Escape character is '^]'.
```

The `Connected to google.com` response demonstrates that your machine has made a successful connection to the port and IP address.  Otherwise, it will hang at the `Trying x.x.x.x...` line.

Another possibility is that your intranet is set up to go through a proxy server -- you make a connection internally to a machine in your network, and it in turn makes the actual connection.  This can screw things up -- not sure what you would need to do to handle that, but something special -- browsers have special settings for handling proxy servers, so your Rails code would need to, as well.