# ruby 2.5: set timeout on tcp socket's read

Tags: ruby, sockets, timeout, ruby-2.5

Ruby 2.5's [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html)
says that for:
`myTCPServer = Socket.tcp(host, port, nil, nil, :connect_timeout=60)`,
the only option it accepts is `:connect_timeout`.

(Ruby 2.0's [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-tcp_server_sockets) may have a copy-paste error,
claiming that `:timeout` is another option, but not saying what that option does.  At any rate, that option doesn't work in 2.5.1p57 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.)

Is the gem [tcp_timeout](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tcp_timeout/0.1.1) the best way to make a TCP socket whose connected session can **timeout on read** for a specified duration,  e.g via `mySession.gets`?
(Not a timeout on [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21014272/2097284).
Not a timeout on write.)

Or [`IO::select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853516/set-socket-timeout-in-ruby-via-so-rcvtimeo-socket-option?rq=1)?

Comment: "The best way"? Who knows. There does not appear to be a built-in way. tcp_timeout uses IO::select under the hood, so that approach definitely works. A simple thread-based timer might also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [IO::select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853516/set-socket-timeout-in-ruby-via-so-rcvtimeo-socket-option?rq=1), using `recvfrom` instead of `gets` (which might wait a while for a newline).