# Suppress nil response from Ruby method

Tags: ruby, tcp, nagios

I've been tasked with modifying an existing Ruby script, but my Ruby knowledge is basic at best...
I need to add a method to check if a server's port is open. if it is, the script should resume doing whatever it's doing. if not, it should exit.

I've applied the following method, taken from [Ruby - See if a port is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517219/ruby-see-if-a-port-is-open/517638#517638):

```
def is_port_open?
  @host = "localhost"
  @port = "8080"
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(1) do
      begin
        s = TCPSocket.new(@host, @port)
        s.close
      rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
        return "port closed :("
      end
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
  end
  return "problem with timeout?"
end
```

This method seems to work well, except when returning "nil" if the port is open. How do i suppress any output (unless there is an error)?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It looks to me like this will always return `"problem with timeout?"` unless the port is closed. What do you mean about returning `nil`?

Comment: You should consider changing the name of the method. The coding convention in Ruby is that methods ending in a "?" will return a truthy or falsey value which is used in conditional statements. Someone not knowing this returns a String might try to use it in a conditional statement only to find it always passes. (2 cents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you only need to check for a condition (port is open):

```
require 'timeout'
require 'socket'

def is_port_open? host, port
  @host = host || "localhost"
  @port = port || "8080"
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(1) do
      begin
        s = TCPSocket.new(@host, @port)
        s.close
        return true # success
      rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
        return false # socket error 
      end 
    end 
  rescue Timeout::Error
  end 
  return false # timeout error
end

is_port_open? 'localhost', 8080
#⇒ true
is_port_open? 'localhost', 11111
#⇒ false
```

It’s now up to you what to return in case of error etc. Please note, that another option would be to let exceptions propagate to caller. This function would be a way shorter, but you’ll need to handle exceptions in caller.

Comment: Thanks! it seems that my original problem was that i called the method by using "puts"... o.0 (and so the result was printed out).